# Vuex: Can mutations contain conditional statements?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Can mutations contain conditional statements, like here?

```
 const mutations = {
      getResponse(state, response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          state.item.data = response.data;
        } else {
          state.item.errorText = response;
        }
     },
```

Comment: yes but this makes it harder to debug. Try putting the conditional statements in action and keep the mutation clear and simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from doing this AFAIK, as long as it's synchronous it will run - but it's not exactly idiomatic. You'd be better-off having 2 mutations, and checking the status in your action.

```
const mutations = {
    responseData(state, response) {
        state.item.data = response.data;
    },
    responseError(state, response) {
        state.item.errorText = response;
    },
};
```